# How to add parameters to plugins in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, tinymce, joomla3.0

I use some plugins in Joomla, which has parameters.
When it's not Joomla, in index.html I set these parameters like:

```
<script>
      tinymce.init({
            selector: '#tinymce',
            plugins: 'pluginName',
            pluginName: {
                parameterName: "value"
            }
      });
</script>
```

But unfortunately, there's no tinyMCE.init in Joomla.
I tried to find the place in `/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php` for this plugin settings, but can't.

Is there a way to add plugin settings/parameters in any Joomla files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that parameters can be setup in **$scriptOptions** variable. `/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php` ~625th line.
If plugin has parameters structure like:

```
pluginName: {
    parameterName: "value"
}
```

it must be written there like: `'pluginName' => array(parameterName => 'value'),`
[image]

The plugin itself can be added through Joomla admin panel: `Extensions -> Plugins -> Editor - TinyMCE -> Custom Plugin`